# How to get closest Material color from a Color?

Tags: flutter, dart, colors

Is there any way of getting a closest `MaterialColor` from a `Color` object? Let's say I've

```
Color someColor = Color(0xFF212122); // Not a MaterialColor
```

The closest material color to above color is `Color(0xFF212121)`. Is there any method of getting it programmatically?

Comment: what do you mean by "closest"? you can have any `MaterialColor` you want as it has `MaterialColor(int primary, Map<int, Color> swatch)` constructor

Comment: @pskink Actually I already have a color and I need to know a material color which is closest to it. In `MaterialColor` constructor, you also need to pass swatch (additional value).

Comment: so use `HSVColor` to fill the `swatch` map (or any other way, for example `Color.alphaBlend` or `Color.lerp`)